# Linear distance is proportional to angular distance, why?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

Im my Fourier series book, the following is stated:

We may specify the position of a point on the circle by its angular coordinate $\theta$, measured from some fixed base point. Since linear distance on a circle is proportional to angular distance, we can write:

$$\Delta x = r\Delta \theta,$$

where $r$ is the radius. Here is the part from my book:

[image]

I'm curious to know, where does the equation $\Delta x = r\Delta \theta$ come from? Why is it so? Is my interpretation of linear distance and angular distance correct in this picture:

[image]

Thank you for any help =)

Comment: It's only true in the limit. $$\Delta x = 2r\sin \frac{\Delta \theta}{2},$$ so for small $\Delta\theta$, the approximation is good, and in the limit it becomes exact in the sense $$\lim_{\Delta\theta\to 0} \frac{r\Delta\theta}{\Delta x} = 1.$$

Comment: FWIW, my reading is different. In the stated context, "linear distance" suggests "arc length", while "angular distance" is $\Delta\theta$, the angular difference measured at the center of the circle. These quantities are indeed (exactly) proportional, with the radius $r$ as constant of proportionality. (I'm not saying "linear distance" is a good name for arc length, but it _is_ distance as measured inside the $1$-D universe of the circle.)

Comment: @user86418: Would you turn your comment into an answer? I'd read it the same way.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Your comment would be better posted as an answer, too, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, "linear distance" appears to mean "arc length"[*], while "angular distance" is presumably $\Delta\theta$, the angular difference measured at the center of the circle. These quantities are indeed proportional, with the radius $r$ as constant of proportionality.

[*] Note, for example, that arc length (rather than chord length) is the relevant coordinate for describing heat flow in the circle. :)